# How to give vertex shader to a geometry without changing the material in threeJS?

Tags: graphics, three.js, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I am trying to modify some geometries with my vertex shader, it basically applies certain linear transforms to each vertex of the geometry and hence altering its shape. The problem is I can't figure out how to enable phong lighting and textures with this. As soon as I pass my vertex shader through material API it automatically assumes red color and everything looks flat. Looks like there is no lighting calculation going on here. Kindly help.

Heres a demo where I am applying my vertex shader to a cube.
https://jsfiddle.net/6593Lyve/4/

```
void main()
{
    vec3 p = position.xyz;
    float new_x = p.x*a11 + p.y*a12;
    float new_y = p.x*a21 + p.y*a22;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(new_x, new_y, p.z, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: If you want to keep threejs' phong lighting intact with custom vertex transforms, you'll likely want to modify an existing shader rather than writing one from scratch. See this example: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=instanc#webgl_buffergeometry_instancing_lambert, which does instancing but could similarly transform vertices separately.

Comment: If you just want to hack in simple lighting, see https://jsfiddle.net/6bg4qdhx/3/. Alternatively, see https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_modified.html.

Comment: your question doesn't have enough code in it to debug without having to go offsite to look at your code so it is off topic for stack overflow. Please put all the relevant code **in the question itself**.

Comment: Thanks @WestLangley, it serves the purpose of my project but it looks weird when the value goes negative https://jsfiddle.net/hr14w3tz/1/

Comment: When you update vertex positions, the normals are no longer correct. You either need to update normals, too, or use flat shading, which doesn't require normals.

Answer (score 6):

If you want the full material features then you should modify an existing shader using `material.onBeforeCompile`

```js
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(...);
material.onBeforeCompile = function(info) {
  // change info.vertexShader, info.fragmentShader, and/or info.uniforms here
  console.log(info)
};
```

If you run this it will and inspect it in the JavaScript console it will print out something like

```
{name: "MeshPhongMaterial", uniforms: {…}, vertexShader: "#define PHONG↵varying vec3 vViewPosition;↵#ifndef …clude <shadowmap_vertex>↵  #include <fog_vertex>↵}", fragmentShader: "#define PHONG↵uniform vec3 diffuse;↵uniform vec3 e…_alpha_fragment>↵ #include <dithering_fragment>↵}"}
name: "MeshPhongMaterial"
uniforms:
diffuse: {value: Color}
opacity: {value: 1}
map: {value: null}
uvTransform: {value: Matrix3}
alphaMap: {value: null}
specularMap: {value: null}
envMap: {value: null}
flipEnvMap: {value: -1}
reflectivity: {value: 1}
refractionRatio: {value: 0.98}
maxMipLevel: {value: 0}
aoMap: {value: null}
aoMapIntensity: {value: 1}
lightMap: {value: null}
lightMapIntensity: {value: 1}
emissiveMap: {value: null}
bumpMap: {value: null}
bumpScale: {value: 1}
normalMap: {value: null}
normalScale: {value: Vector2}
displacementMap: {value: null}
displacementScale: {value: 1}
displacementBias: {value: 0}
gradientMap: {value: null}
fogDensity: {value: 0.00025}
fogNear: {value: 1}
fogFar: {value: 2000}
fogColor: {value: Color}
ambientLightColor: {value: Array(3), needsUpdate: true}
lightProbe: {value: Array(9), needsUpdate: true}
directionalLights: {value: Array(1), properties: {…}, needsUpdate: true}
directionalShadowMap: {value: Array(0)}
directionalShadowMatrix: {value: Array(0)}
spotLights: {value: Array(0), properties: {…}, needsUpdate: true}
spotShadowMap: {value: Array(0)}
spotShadowMatrix: {value: Array(0)}
pointLights: {value: Array(0), properties: {…}, needsUpdate: true}
pointShadowMap: {value: Array(0)}
pointShadowMatrix: {value: Array(0)}
hemisphereLights: {value: Array(0), properties: {…}, needsUpdate: true}
rectAreaLights: {value: Array(0), properties: {…}, needsUpdate: true}
emissive: {value: Color}
specular: {value: Color}
shininess: {value: 30}
clippingPlanes: {value: null, needsUpdate: false}
__proto__: Object
vertexShader: "#define PHONG↵varying vec3 vViewPosition;↵#ifndef FLAT_SHADED↵   varying vec3 vNormal;↵#endif↵#include <common>↵#include <uv_pars_vertex>↵#include <uv2_pars_vertex>↵#include <displacementmap_pars_vertex>↵#include <envmap_pars_vertex>↵#include <color_pars_vertex>↵#include <fog_pars_vertex>↵#include <morphtarget_pars_vertex>↵#include <skinning_pars_vertex>↵#include <shadowmap_pars_vertex>↵#include <logdepthbuf_pars_vertex>↵#include <clipping_planes_pars_vertex>↵void main() {↵   #include <uv_vertex>↵   #include <uv2_vertex>↵  #include <color_vertex>↵    #include <beginnormal_vertex>↵  #include <morphnormal_vertex>↵  #include <skinbase_vertex>↵ #include <skinnormal_vertex>↵   #include <defaultnormal_vertex>↵#ifndef FLAT_SHADED↵    vNormal = normalize( transformedNormal );↵#endif↵   #include <begin_vertex>↵    #include <morphtarget_vertex>↵  #include <skinning_vertex>↵ #include <displacementmap_vertex>↵  #include <project_vertex>↵  #include <logdepthbuf_vertex>↵  #include <clipping_planes_vertex>↵  vViewPosition = - mvPosition.xyz;↵  #include <worldpos_vertex>↵ #include <envmap_vertex>↵   #include <shadowmap_vertex>↵    #include <fog_vertex>↵}"
fragmentShader: "#define PHONG↵uniform vec3 diffuse;↵uniform vec3 emissive;↵uniform vec3 specular;↵uniform float shininess;↵uniform float opacity;↵#include <common>↵#include <packing>↵#include <dithering_pars_fragment>↵#include <color_pars_fragment>↵#include <uv_pars_fragment>↵#include <uv2_pars_fragment>↵#include <map_pars_fragment>↵#include <alphamap_pars_fragment>↵#include <aomap_pars_fragment>↵#include <lightmap_pars_fragment>↵#include <emissivemap_pars_fragment>↵#include <envmap_common_pars_fragment>↵#include <envmap_pars_fragment>↵#include <gradientmap_pars_fragment>↵#include <fog_pars_fragment>↵#include <bsdfs>↵#include <lights_pars_begin>↵#include <lights_phong_pars_fragment>↵#include <shadowmap_pars_fragment>↵#include <bumpmap_pars_fragment>↵#include <normalmap_pars_fragment>↵#include <specularmap_pars_fragment>↵#include <logdepthbuf_pars_fragment>↵#include <clipping_planes_pars_fragment>↵void main() {↵   #include <clipping_planes_fragment>↵    vec4 diffuseColor = vec4( diffuse, opacity );↵  ReflectedLight reflectedLight = ReflectedLight( vec3( 0.0 ), vec3( 0.0 ), vec3( 0.0 ), vec3( 0.0 ) );↵  vec3 totalEmissiveRadiance = emissive;↵ #include <logdepthbuf_fragment>↵    #include <map_fragment>↵    #include <color_fragment>↵  #include <alphamap_fragment>↵   #include <alphatest_fragment>↵  #include <specularmap_fragment>↵    #include <normal_fragment_begin>↵   #include <normal_fragment_maps>↵    #include <emissivemap_fragment>↵    #include <lights_phong_fragment>↵   #include <lights_fragment_begin>↵   #include <lights_fragment_maps>↵    #include <lights_fragment_end>↵ #include <aomap_fragment>↵  vec3 outgoingLight = reflectedLight.directDiffuse + reflectedLight.indirectDiffuse + reflectedLight.directSpecular + reflectedLight.indirectSpecular + totalEmissiveRadiance;↵  #include <envmap_fragment>↵ gl_FragColor = vec4( outgoingLight, diffuseColor.a );↵  #include <tonemapping_fragment>↵    #include <encodings_fragment>↵  #include <fog_fragment>↵    #include <premultiplied_alpha_fragment>↵    #include <dithering_fragment>↵}"
__proto__: Object
```

Where the vertex shader is

```c
#define PHONG
varying vec3 vViewPosition;
#ifndef FLAT_SHADED
    varying vec3 vNormal;
#endif
#include <common>
#include <uv_pars_vertex>
#include <uv2_pars_vertex>
#include <displacementmap_pars_vertex>
#include <envmap_pars_vertex>
#include <color_pars_vertex>
#include <fog_pars_vertex>
#include <morphtarget_pars_vertex>
#include <skinning_pars_vertex>
#include <shadowmap_pars_vertex>
#include <logdepthbuf_pars_vertex>
#include <clipping_planes_pars_vertex>
void main() {
    #include <uv_vertex>
    #include <uv2_vertex>
    #include <color_vertex>
    #include <beginnormal_vertex>
    #include <morphnormal_vertex>
    #include <skinbase_vertex>
    #include <skinnormal_vertex>
    #include <defaultnormal_vertex>
#ifndef FLAT_SHADED
    vNormal = normalize( transformedNormal );
#endif
    #include <begin_vertex>
    #include <morphtarget_vertex>
    #include <skinning_vertex>
    #include <displacementmap_vertex>
    #include <project_vertex>
    #include <logdepthbuf_vertex>
    #include <clipping_planes_vertex>
    vViewPosition = - mvPosition.xyz;
    #include <worldpos_vertex>
    #include <envmap_vertex>
    #include <shadowmap_vertex>
    #include <fog_vertex>
}
```

Now you can search and replace parts of the shader

Looking though the referenced [shader chunks](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk) it looks like [`begin_vertex`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/begin_vertex.glsl.js) is the one you want .

It looks like this

```c
vec3 transformed = vec3( position );
```

So your code could be something like

```c
vec3 p = position.xyz;
float new_x = p.x*a11 + p.y*a12;
float new_y = p.x*a21 + p.y*a22;
vec3 transformed = vec4(new_x, new_y, p.z);
```

Which you could add like this, you also need to add your uniforms

```js
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(...);
material.onBeforeCompile = function(info) {
  info.vertexShader = info.vertexShader.replace('#include <begin_vertex>', `
    vec3 p = position.xyz;
    float new_x = p.x*a11 + p.y*a12;
    float new_y = p.x*a21 + p.y*a22;
    vec3 transformed = vec4(new_x, new_y, p.z);
  `).replace('#include <common>', `
     #include <common>
     uniform float a11;
     uniform float a12;
     uniform float a21;
     uniform float a22;
  `).
  info.uniforms.a11 = { value: 0 };
  info.uniforms.a12 = { value: 0 };
  info.uniforms.a21 = { value: 0 };
  info.uniforms.a22 = { value: 0 };
};
```

Comment: This should probably be accepted as the correct answer. This is very well explained and helpful.